# Format fields in twitter bootstrap to show like a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not the best when it comes to CSS to here goes.

I'm trying to format fields in twitter bootstrap by strictly using CSS / javascript (or jQuery)

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="span12">
    <div id="DOB_picker" class="DOB_picker">
        <fieldset class="birthday-picker">
            <label for="birth[month]">Month</label>
            <select class="birth-month" name="birth[month]"></select>

            <label for="birth[day]">Day</label>
            <select class="birth-day" name="birth[day]">

            <label for="birth[year]">Year</label>
            <select class="birth-year" name="birth[year]"></select>         
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can not change the HTML as it is auto generated and therefore the only way for me to style it is CSS or javascript.

**This is what it looks like right now**

[image]

**EDIT: After trying reagan's Solution**

```
var html = $('.birthday-picker').html();
$('.birthday-picker').html('<row>' + html + '</row>');
```

I used the following code to try to implement reagan's solution but had no luck :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you requested a **CSS / JS only** solution..

You will need to wrap your `label & select` elements with a  element `(.control-group)`

```
$("#DOB_picker").find("label").each(function(){

     $(this).nextUntil("label").andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='control-group'></div>");
});
```

​

Your `.control-group` will need the following css, or similar

```
   #DOB_picker .control-group {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    float: left;
    }

    #DOB_picker .control-group label {
    text-align:left;
    }
```

You really want to put this CSS under custom, semantic classes so it doesn't trash the rest of your site.

---

**Working Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/nJm2C/

Answer (score 2):

surround your fields with a `<row></row>` like so:

```
<div class="span12">
    <div id="DOB_picker" class="DOB_picker">
        <fieldset class="birthday-picker">
            <row>
                <label for="birth[month]">Month</label>
                <select class="birth-month" name="birth[month]"></select>

                <label for="birth[day]">Day</label>
                <select class="birth-day" name="birth[day]">

                <label for="birth[year]">Year</label>
                <select class="birth-year" name="birth[year]"></select>
            </row>        
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

That should make them all be inline (and if it doesn't it's because your inputs and/or labels are too wide to all be inline.

Comment: did you read the question? it clearly states.. I can not change the HTML as it is auto generated and therefore the only way for me to style it is CSS or javascript.

Comment: I am a big fan of this jQuery solution. It's fairly light-weight, carries little overhead, and, providing you're not doing this 1000 times on a page, it won't slow anything down in the slightest, even in IE.

Comment: sure give me a second and I'll write it for you as an answer

Comment: something like 
`$insertbefore = '<row>';`
`$insertafter = '</row>';`
`$insertbefore.insertAfter('.birthday-picker');`
`$insertafter.insertAfter('.last-select');`

would work if you gave your last select that `.last-select` class

Comment: I already have that. Even after doing it that way it still does not work. The new HTML markup looks exactly like this answer but still does not work. Look at my updated question (at the bottom)

Comment: @reagan, you should have quit while you were ahead: that is the most ridiculous jQuery solution I've ever seen considering there are several jQuery functions dealing with wrapping, one of which (jQuery.wrap()) will do everything you just said in one line, more efficiently, and more reliably ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help but Blowsie's solution worked. Look at @Blowsie's solution and upvote him. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11744599/973155

Comment: lol I wasn't trying to be rude. Just trying to teach you. I was giggling as I typed it - I think it came out a lot harsher than I meant to - emphasis was supposed to be on the ;) Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
<div class="span12">
    <div id="DOB_picker" class="DOB_picker">
        <fieldset class="row-fluid birthday-picker">
            <div class="span4">
              <label for="birth[month]">Month</label>
              <select class="birth-month" name="birth[month]"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
              <label for="birth[day]">Day</label>
              <select class="birth-day" name="birth[day]">
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
              <label for="birth[year]">Year</label>
              <select class="birth-year" name="birth[year]"></select>
            </div>         
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you read the question? it clearly states.. I can not change the HTML as it is auto generated and therefore the only way for me to style it is CSS or javascript.

Comment: Well, what if whole this code is in some div with width:300px? Then he will never get those select fields in row.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is the jQuery to wrap your content in rows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ...
    $("#DOB_picker").wrap("<div class='row' />");
    ...
});
```

The one thing that you're going to have to play around with is what class you give the div that you're going to wrap with (I used row, as it is the likely case). The reason I can't give you this answer is because your page layout could be different and could require a 'row-fluid'. You will know when you see it. Here is a link to the [Bootstrap Documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) in case you need to use a different class.

Let me know if you ahve any questions.

Comment: first off, you need to click the bootstrap checkbox next to the fiddle

Comment: you dont need either of those, i already included the bootstrap css and onload is just as good as doc ready in this case. your suggestions dont work , see here. http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/nJm2C/3/

Comment: third off, you need to add the class span4 to all those divs (that part I did not do for you - you should have read the documentation)

Comment: @Blowsie: SO is a teaching/learning site - we're not supposed to just do your work for you even though we sometimes do. This is the answer you want. Review the documentation and add the class span4. If I have time, I'll post it myself, but you can't count on us to just give you the code, hence my ellipses in the solution that I gave

Comment: I often find answers that extend way past "read the documentation" are most useful. Each to their own.

Comment: Like @Blowsie said, your solution does not work. I have tried it. Thanks for your effort thought :)