# Horizontal fields in Form using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter bootstrap for creating my form. My objective is to create two rows (actually more, but I'm simplifying it for making the question simple) in the form. The first row contains three labels. And the second row will contain three input box for obtaining text as input.

I have written the following code for acheiving that:

```
<div class="span6" id="create_trips" >
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method='post' action=''>
                        <fieldset>

                            <legend>
                                Test
                            </legend>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">test1</label>
                                <label class="control-label">test2</label>
                                <label class="control-label">test3</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" class="input-mini">
                                </div>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" class="input-mini">
                                </div>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" class="input-mini">
                                </div>
                            </div>                              
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

But the problem is the second row is completely unaligned. Whereas my first row is proper. I have attached the current output produced by the above code here: [image: Output]

Comment: Have you tried a pull-left on the DIV controls?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format fields in twitter bootstrap to show like a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744495/format-fields-in-twitter-bootstrap-to-show-like-a-table)

Comment: @Pleun Yeah, I tried it just now, but it doesn't help in achieving my objective.

Comment: @Blowsie The other question doesn't use `form class="form-horizontal"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem using some custom CSS and changing the class name in the HTML code. Here is the HTML code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method='post' action=''>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Test</legend>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-trip" style="text-align: center">test1</label>
        <label class="control-trip" style="text-align: center">test2</label>
        <label class="control-trip" style="text-align: center">test3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="control-trip">
            <input type="text" class="input-mini">
        </div>
        <div class="control-trip">
            <input type="text" class="input-mini">
        </div>
        <div class="control-trip">
            <input type="text" class="input-mini">
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

And here is the corresponding CSS:

```
   .form-horizontal .control-trip
{
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

The solution is here in this [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3Mzs2/7/)

Answer (score 1):

You've 12 cols in bootstrap... So create 3 cols by row like the following :

```
<!-- The row -->
<div class="row-fluid">
  <!-- One col -->
  <div class="span4">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">test1</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" ... />
      </div>                    
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Another col -->
  <div class="span4">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">test1</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" ... />
      </div>                    
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- The last col -->
  <div class="span4">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">test1</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" ... />
      </div>                    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Another row -->
<div class="row-fluid">
  <!-- One col -->
  <div class="span4">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">test1</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" ... />
      </div>                    
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Another col -->
  <div class="span4">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">test1</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" ... />
      </div>                    
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- The last col -->
  <div class="span4">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">test1</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" ... />
      </div>                    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know that it has 12 columns, but the remaining are allocated for different purposes. Anyway, I can try your method using `span2`.

Comment: yeah, of course you can adapt the code to your needs ;) tell me if it helps you or if you need more accurate solution